# Fill field value while page is loading in HTML Page

Tags: html

I have a third part web address (www.samplespage.com). I call this page from another web site. is it possibe to fill some field values before page load or after page load? I tried vith URL parameters but It did not work.

www.samplespage.com?id=fieldId&value=fieldValue

This is how it looks like in codes. (I picked up from source via F12 Development tools in IE)

```
<input name="fieldName" id="fieldId" size="12" maxlength="11" value="">
```

Comment: Unless you control samplespages or it has an API you can access, no. SamplesPages would have to have been coded in such a way to recieve this information.

Comment: When I try this It works
http://www.samplespage.com/test.html?fieldId=value

What i need to do is to fill a .JSP page like 
http://www.samplespage.com/test.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When It's an HTML page It works with URL parameters otherwise You need to use like Selenium or Ptyhon ..